# How to debug using Visual Studio on load balanced WFEs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, visual-studio, load-balancing

I have a 4 server farm.

APP
WFE1
WFE2
DB

Both WFE1 and WFE2 are load balanced and their network name is `SPLOAD`.
So basically I can open `http://spload` in browser and it opens website from one of those servers depending on to whom load balancer sends request.

I installed Visual Studio 2012 on APP, WFE1 and WFE2 but VS doesn't accept `http://spload` in SITE URL field in project properties and throws following error:

```
Remote SharePoint site connections are not supported.
```

How do I debug site in VS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line to the hosts file `("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts")` on all of your SharePoint Servers:

```
127.0.0.1 SPLOAD
```

That'll make them always use themselves as the server when referring to SPLOAD instead of having to go through the load balancer and maybe start talking to one of the other servers